# Oracle Enterprise Manger Agent not working, making it not possible to configure EM DB console

Tags: database, oracle, oracle11g, oracle-enterprise-manager

I have installed oracle database 11gR2 on Oracle linux 7.2. However, oracle enterprise manager was not working. I tried to figure our what was wrong and a long search, i came across a blog that suggested that I should reconfigure EM. using the following command

```
#emca -config dbcontrol db -repos recreate
```

This command started well, but failed at the point where it securing the DB console with the following error.

Error securing Database Control, Database Control has been brought up in non-secure mode. To secure the Database Control execute the following command(s):

```
 1) Set the environment variable ORACLE_SID to orcl    

 2) /u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0.4/db_1/bin/emctl stop dbconsole   

 3) /u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0.4/db_1/bin/emctl config emkey -repos

 4) -sysman_pwd < Password for SYSMAN user            /u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0.4/db_1/bin/emctl secure dbconsole
  -sysman_pwd < Password for SYSMAN user >    

 5) /u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0.4/db_1/bin/emctl start dbconsole

 To secure Em Key, run /u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0.4/db_1/bin/emctl config       emkey -remove_from_repos -sysman_pwd < Password for SYSMAN user >
 Aug 3, 2016 3:48:30 PM oracle.sysman.emcp.EMConfig perform
```

The problem lies in executing step (4) above.
Each time i run command of step 4, i get the following error

```
*[04-08-2016 12:00:39] USERINFO ::DBCONSOLE already stopped...   Done.
[04-08-2016 12:00:39] USERINFO ::Failed to stop agent...*
```

The command *emctl stop agent* is not recognised as well as *emctl start agent*

Below are the contents of some log files

```
1. **emagent.log**
 *2016-08-03 16:00:48,520 Thread-1268766464 target {orcl.cc, oracle_database} is broken: cannot compute dynamic properties in time. (00155)
2016-08-03 16:00:48,648 Thread-1268766464 enable collector (00407)
2016-08-03 16:00:49,678 Thread-1262466816 <Upload Manager> Exceeded Max allowed Upload data - No of files: 139, Size of upload data: 129.344502MB, Pct(%) of Disk used: 42.30%, Disabling collections (00852)
2016-08-03 16:00:49,678 Thread-1262466816 Disable collector (00406)
2016-08-03 16:20:29,822 Thread-1268766464 target {orcl.cc, oracle_database} is broken: cannot compute dynamic properties in time. (00155)
2016-08-03 16:20:29,950 Thread-1268766464 enable collector (00407)
2016-08-03 16:20:30,980 Thread-1256167168 <Upload Manager> Exceeded Max allowed Upload data - No of files: 144, Size of upload data: 137.557024MB, Pct(%) of Disk used: 42.32%, Disabling collections (00852)
2016-08-03 16:20:30,980 Thread-1256167168 Disable collector (00406)
2016-08-04 11:08:31,475 Thread-1275066112 enable collector (00407)
2016-08-04 11:22:21,057 Thread-977835840 Starting Agent 10.2.0.4.2 from /u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0.4/db_1 (00701)
2016-08-04 11:22:21,058 Thread-977835840 <Agent Startup> : Startup of HTTP LISTENER failure (00716)
2016-08-04 11:59:13,322 Thread-3109705536 running as user 0, not 54321 (00005)
2016-08-04 11:59:13,323 Thread-3109705536 <Agent Startup> : The Agent was started by a user who does not own emd.properties - aborting startup (00709)
2016-08-04 12:00:59,562 Thread-1832347456 Starting Agent 10.2.0.4.2 from /u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0.4/db_1 (00701)
2016-08-04 12:00:59,563 Thread-1832347456 <Agent Startup> : Startup of HTTP LISTENER failure (00716)
2016-08-04 12:18:03,609 Thread-2117162816 Starting Agent 10.2.0.4.2 from /u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0.4/db_1 (00701)
2016-08-04 12:18:03,609 Thread-2117162816 <Agent Startup> : Startup of HTTP LISTENER failure (00716)
2016-08-04 12:20:30,742 Thread-404399936 Starting Agent 10.2.0.4.2 from /u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0.4/db_1 (00701)
2016-08-04 12:20:30,743 Thread-404399936 <Agent Startup> : Startup of HTTP LISTENER failure (00716) *
```

> My agent  version is 10.2.0.4.0
>
> my DB control version is 11.2.0.1.0

I cant stop nor start the agent. this prevents me from proceeding with whatever help in I get on the internet because it requires starting and stopping the agent.

When i run the command `*#emctl status agent*`, i get the following out put

> *Oracle Enterprise manager 11g DB Control version 11.2.0.1.0
>
> Copyright (C) 1996, 2009 Oracle Corporation. All right reserved.*

Please I have been trying to solve this for the pas 5 days, but i always get stuck by when there's any step involving starting or stopping the agent.
So i guest my main problem is the agent.

Answer (score 0):

To enable Oracle Enterprise Manager on Oracle Linux 7.x you need to upgrade the Oracle Database Server and Oracle Database to version 11.2.0.4.0. After that the Oracle patch "19692824: DBCONTROL is not coming up on OEL 7" must be installed to upgrade the version of OEM Agent.

Finally you can enable OEM with HTTPS using the command:

```
emca -config dbcontrol db -repos create
```

Note: The patch 19692824 is not compatible with Oracle Database Server 11.2.0.3.0